# How to access local host through tor browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, development

Hi I'm doing some web development and wanted to be able to do some cross browser testing. Normally I would just point which ever browser I'm using at localhost and go from there.

Unfortunately Tor Browser seems to be unable to reach the address. I don't want to expose any unfinished work to the public internet and prefer the convenience of working locally. Any suggestions?

Comment: socks5 proxy localhost:9150

Answer (score 8):

Go to `about:config` and set `network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost = false`.

This stops `http[s]://127.0.0.1` from being proxied through Tor. But make sure to request the IP, not by `localhost` or another hostname, as the browser my still try to DNS-resolve those through Tor and fail.

Alternatively, you can set a whitelist via e.g. `network.proxy.no_proxies_on = "127.0.0.1,192.168.1.1"`.

If these measures don't work, also try to disable the NoScript extension at `about:addons`. Finally, needless to say that tampering with your proxy and security settings should only be for testing as it may compromise your anonymity.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* set up an onion service with [`HiddenServiceAuthorizeClient`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#HiddenServiceAuthorizeClient), that would allow you, and only you, to access localhost resources through Tor Browser without any modifications or special settings. This is the least likely to fail catastrophically.

*If* and *only if* you are going to use it to view *purely* localhost content (e.g. you don't reference external resources on the site) then you might try this:

Set aside a distinct and clearly marked copy of Tor Browser then [follow this guide](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TorBrowserBundleSAQ#UsinganupstreamTorTransProxydaemon) to use Tor Browser with an upstream transproxy, this will make Tor Browser disable its own proxying and just connect directly. You can skip the bits about the control port and ignore the Tor Button errors since you're not using Tor at all.

I *cannot* stress enough just how important it is that you *do not* allow those environment variables to affect (infect?) any copy of Tor Browser you intend to use for actual browsing. Possibly you want to do this from a computer that is totally disconnected from the network, to be certain.

Answer (score 2):

By far the easiest and safest is to start a local `.onion` service, then connect to it normally.

1. Create an empty folder somewhere, e.g. `C:/my/keys/test1`
2. Then add this to `torrc`:

   ```
    HiddenServiceDir C:/my/keys/test1
    HiddenServiceVersion 3
    HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
   ```

   On Windows, `torrc` is at `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor/`

   On Linux/MacOS `torrc` is located at `[install directory]/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/`
3. Now restart your Tor Browser, and it'll create a file `C:/my/keys/test1/hostname`, which will contain the .onion address pointing to your `localhost:80`

Answer (score 0):

Further info:
As said above, if you want to access pages on your local network via the Tor Browser you can't by default - why not, and why it isn't an option in the main configuration, is beyond me!

How to Fix:

1. Type in to the address bar "about:config" - ignore the quotes!
2. Type "network.proxy.no_proxies_on" in to the search bar.
3. Click on the pen icon and copy / paste the following in to the blank box:
   "localhost, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.0/24" - again without the quotes!
4. Hit Enter/Return
   Tor will be disabled for everything inside your local network but still work in the big, bad, world!

Note:
192.168.0.0/24 - will disable Tor assuming the local IP addresses assigned by your router are of the form 192.168.0.x
If this is not the case you will need to swap this value for the one your router does provide, eg:
If 192.168.1.x then 192.168.1.0/24, and so on.
Do take care not to get cute and try to expand the range too much. Any address you 'disable' is disabled everywhere.

P.S.
As a point of security most/many routers assign LAN addresses in the form 192.168.0.x or 192.168.1.x The result is 'naughty' software looks for these IP addresses when trying to do 'naughty' things. It's not a bad idea at all to reconfigure your router for another less commonly used address range, eg: 10.55.101.x or whatever, and if possible set it to automatically reboot once a week at a time when a reboot won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

urther info: As said above, if you want to access pages on your local network via the Tor Browser you can't by default - why not, and why it isn't an option in the main configuration, is beyond me!

How to Fix:

Type in to the address bar "about:config" - ignore the quotes!
Type "network.proxy.no_proxies_on" in to the search bar.
Click on the pen icon and copy / paste the following in to the blank box: "localhost, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.0/24" - again without the quotes!
Hit Enter/Return Tor will be disabled for everything inside your local network but still work in the big, bad, world!
Note: 192.168.0.0/24 - will disable Tor assuming the local IP addresses assigned by your router are of the form 192.168.0.x If this is not the case you will need to swap this value for the one your router does provide, eg: If 192.168.1.x then 192.168.1.0/24, and so on. Do take care not to get cute and try to expand the range too much. Any address you 'disable' is disabled everywhere.

P.S. As a point of security most/many routers assign LAN addresses in the form 192.168.0.x or 192.168.1.x The result is 'naughty' software looks for these IP addresses when trying to do 'naughty' things. It's not a bad idea at all to reconfigure your router for another less commonly used address range, eg: 10.55.101.x or whatever, and if possible set it to automatically reboot once a week at a time when a reboot won't matter.